# Compiling whole report

Tags: compiling, report

I have a report seperated into many tex-files. I have 2 questions:

- Is it possible to see just one tex-file in pdf? How can I do it?
- How can I compile the whole report and the associated tex-files in just one click? Now I need to compile a underlaying document, then the whole report to see the pdf in the latest version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to combine multiple TeX files into a single one (which is needed if you want to compile it with a single step into a single PDF) you'll need to use the `\include` macro that will basically copy the text from the referenced file and paste it into the current document at the position the `\include` has been encountered (to be more precise that's how `\input` works - but those are details that don't really matter at this point).

You will have to separate out the preamble of your documents into the main document though and you may also only have one document environment in all files (the one in the main document you are including the other documents into).

For further information on how include (and input) works, you can have a look at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents and/or https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/include.html